# Text disappears when attachments are downloaded

Tags: attachments, yahoo-mail

Using AG&G Yahoo Mail on HTC EVO. When I open mail there is message text which I can read. 
When attachments finish downloading the message text disappears never to be seen again.
I can read attachments OK but message text has disappeared.

Comment: What email client are you using?